# what are the best ways to mitigate database i/o bottoleneck for large web sites?

Tags: database, performance, web

For large web sites (traffic wise) that has alot of incoming reads and updates that end up being database I/Os, what're the best ways to mitigate the performance impact? one solution that I can think of is - for write, to cache and then do delayed write (using separate job); for read, use memcached concept. any other better solutions?

Answer (score 4):

Here are the most common solutions to database performance:

- Caching (Memcache, etc)
- Add memory to your database
- More database servers (master/slave or sharding)
- Use a different database type (NoSQL, Redis, etc)
- Indexes to speed up read perf. (careful, too many will affect write performance)
- SSDs (fast SSDs will help a lot)
- RAID
- Optimize/tune SQL queries

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to optimize your queries. Most of the times it is not the disk I/O, but poorly written queries which turn out to be the bottleneck.

You can also cache query results and also entire web pages if the content isn't going to change too often.

Answer (score 2):

It very much depends on the usage pattern and data type. There are really different things to do depending on whether transaction are going to be supported, whether you are interested in full consistency or "eventual consistency", how big the data is (will it all fit in huge memory?), how complex the data and queries are, the list might go on and on.... Lots of variables and only after listing all the constraints/requirements you will be able to make a proper decision. Two general advices though:

- Use SSDs
- Use distributed architecture with distributed "NoSQL" (key/value) approach (only if you do not have to use complex relations and transactions)

Answer (score 2):

10 years ago, the standard answer - besides optimizing your particular database - was scale-out using MySQL in two ways.

Reads can be scaled out in two ways. The first is through caching, which introduces possible inconsistancies and creates a separate cache layer. Reads can also be scaled in MySQL by creating "read replicas", where any database can be queried. Any write must be applied to all servers, so replication doesn't help write throughput.

Writes are scaled through sharding. For example, imagine all users with the last name 'a' are assigned to a certain server. Now imagine a more complicated shard algorithm, where a particular row's primary ID is hashed using a hash function, and distributed to one of a pool of servers.

Facebook is one of the most advanced proponents of a sharded MySQL architecture. You can have individual tables "joined" but you have to write custom code, because you might have to hop from server to server - imagine you want to get your friend's timeline posts, you can't simply join it, you have to write some application code.

Once you shard your database, you can't do joins and range lookups become difficult. This subset is sometimes called CRUD operations, and thus MySQL is overkill. Many Chinese social networks realized this, and use sharded Redis (which is much quicker than MySQL), and have written their own shard layer and application logic layers.

Imagine the next problem in sharding - you want to add a new server, and start assigning some users to that new server.

Another approach is to use a distributed database, which generally comes under the names NoSQL or NewSQL, and have a variety of approaches. Some, like MongoDB, have a sharding system to manage this mapping, but require manual steps to add servers. Cassandra has a more flexible clustering scheme, called a chorded architecture. Systems like CouchBase and Aerospike use a random distribution mechanism that remove the need for a shard layer. Some of these databases can exceed 100,000 to 200,000 requests per second per server, with the lateral scale to add new servers - enough for very large operations. With this style of clustering, you can often get a higher level of redundancy and reliability.

Other distributed approaches represent data in a more efficient way, like a graph database. If you have a problem that is better represented as a graph, then a clustered graph database may be more appropriate.